# indicating out of stock item in PREVIEW

Tags: commerce

I have stock commerce module which is very handy. When item reaches 0, it will say out of stock in the page. However, in the main page where I list the products and small thumbnails, customers don't know if it is sold out or not, unless they click it.

I have seen sites where a small red sign saying out of stock is automatically generated overlapping the preview picture. So at one glance customers know it is out of stock without being annoyed by clicking on it.

Comment: In the past I used to preprocess it and check the stock, if stock was 0, I would pass a variable that modified the template to whatever I wanted (usually, if out of stock TRUE, don't print the add to cart form).

Comment: hi Kevin thanks for your reply. If the item is out of stock, the add to cart button will be greyed out and customer is unable to add to cart. So that is fine. 

But how I indicate this on the main page pictures? so that customer wont click on item only to find it out of stock. I have seen websites with [red flags] indicating out of stock on the preview thumbnail pictures. how do I do that? please help please